# как преобразовать недокачанный файл типа PART в "нормальный" текст?

Tags: расширения

у меня есть файл формата part, который, соответственно расширению, скачался не полностью. Открыв такой файл в текстовом редакторе Sublime Text 3, я увидел текст в 8-ричной (по идее) СС. Пример:

```
4d99 964a 3184 4c08 c747 9127 001d 1128
9b39 79cf 7fbf 65af 01bb 5fe8 f993 d93f
8f21 b76e cbba 9df5 9fa8 4171 4fd8 b14f
51b7 8ac2 a738 6fd2 f4ea 3db0 cb84 b1c0
```

В самом файле должен быть текст/таблица.
Что делать? Писать функцию по переводу... Вот именно — во что переводить эти числа?

p.s. нет, никак не стоит задача скачать таблицу полностью и наслаждаться пользованием. Доступа к ней нет и не может быть более.

Comment: В первую очередь выяснить, какой вообще формат этого файла; во вторую очередь выяснять, насколько этот формат устойчив к повреждениям и возможно ли его вообще восстановить

Comment: первое невозможно. Приблизительно - текст/таблица.
А восстановить это как и что это?

Comment: Если формат неизвестен, значит и сделать с этим файлом ничего не получится. Понятие «текст/таблица» слишком широкое

Comment: типов расширений для представления текст/таблицы ограниченное, хоть и большое количество. Возможно, именно из-за этого будет невозможно перепробовать все варианты? Или из-за того, что сам процесс восстановления невозможно автоматизировать скриптом?